# How to generate POJO's/beans/Entities in SpringBoot(STS) from SqlServer

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, sql-server-2012

Generally we generate tables from Hibernate JPA to Database, but however i want to generate reverse, i.e from Database to Entity (from table to pojo).
Can you please suggest solution for:

1. is it possible?
2. is it recommended(if you have near about 1000 table)?
3. or should I go manually by creating POJO.

(I am using Microsoft SqlServer as DB and Spring boot (STS) in back end)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: If you are using MAVEN then below link might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900234/maven-java-source-code-generation-for-hibernate