# Hibernate: Generate Pojo from DB schema

Tags: hibernate

Is there a Hibernate tool (maven plugin) to generate Pojos from a DB schema? something similar to what jOOQ does?

Comment: http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Okay, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900234/maven-java-source-code-generation-for-hibernate

Comment: You can try liquibase